# Duda con genéricos, ¿Por qué funciona este código?

Tags: java

Recién estoy tomando contacto con los genéricos y tengo varias dudas. La primera, es que no entiendo qué hace exactamente este código y cómo es qué puede llegar a compilar:

```java
    package exercise;

    public class GenereicExample<T> {

        public T var = (T) "hola";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            GenereicExample<Integer> cadena = new GenereicExample<Integer>();

            System.out.println(cadena.var);
        }
    }
```

Simplemente estoy haciendo pruebas para ver cómo funcionan y cómo se usan los genéricos, ese código creo que no tiene ningún tipo de sentido hacerlo así, pero simplemente es para aprender.

A ver, según entiendo al declarar GenericExample como Integer, se supone que la variable "var" es una variable numérica y debería fallar, ¿no? Pues me ejecuta y me muestra hola, así que o algo no he hecho bien o no termino de entender cómo funcionan los genéricos. También puede ser que la clave esté en esta línea:
`public T var = (T) "hola";` No entiendo exactamente que tipo de casting se está ejecutando ahí.

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los genéricos son una ayuda al desarrollador durante la escritura y compilación del código, pero no existen en tiempo de ejecución.Por tanto, algo como

```
void imprime(List<String> textos) {
    String primer = textos.get(0);
    System.out.println(primer);
}
```

En tiempo de ejecución se transforma a:

```
void imprime(List textos) {
    String primer =(String) textos.get(0); //Sin el cast, se consideraría Object
    System.out.println(primer);
}
```

En tu caso, como el tipo no puede existir en tiempo de ejecución y no has puesto una restricción al tipo genérico, tu código se transforma en algo como:

```
public class GenereicExample {

    public Object var = "hola";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenereicExample cadena = new GenereicExample();

        System.out.println(cadena.var);
    }
}
```

Que no dará ningún error de ejecución.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Hasta explicaste la forma como lo interpreta el compilador.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. He de reconocer que no lo acabo de entender del todo, tendré que releerlo hasta que consiga entender cómo funciona.

Gracias!